# BUG YUICompressor with special chars

Tags: java, javascript, css, compression, yui-compressor

I am using the newer version of YUICompressor (2.4.7) to compress my Javascript and CSS files, for a long time, everything was apparently fine...when I realized that the special characters "í" and "Í" are not being converted successfully. Strangely, another special chars are being converted as we expect. Why just "í" and "Í" are not being converted? Because of just these two chars are not OK, I discarded Charset Conflicts between file system and language. It looks like a bug. Could anyone help me with this problem?

See what happens when I convert files:

**Converting CSS**

From:

```
@import url("/láÍíàyout.css");
```

To:

```
@import url("/lá�?íàyout.css");
```

---

**Converting JS**

From:

```
var x = 'cícÍsúlúm irmãêîôûúàá';
```

To:

```
var x="c�c�?súlúm irmãêîôûúàá";
```

Comment: Just to be clear, is your question "How do I make YUICompressor work with `í` and `Í`?" or "How do I work around the fact that YUICompressor corrupts strings with `í` or `Í`?"

Comment: I think both. First I'd to know if it's a particular or a general problem. I dont know if it's really a bug. If it is, I'd like to report to the support team and wait to be fixed. But I didn't find any contact channel easily yet.

Comment: They do have a [ticket system for bugs](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/ucp.php?mode=login&redirect=/projects/yui3/newticket) and a [tutorial on filing a bug](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tutorials/report-bugs/) which may be your best bet as it does look like a real bug to me at first glance.

Comment: I contacted a person from YUI by email to get some support. I also tried to open a ticket at the ticket system, but it's generic for every components from YUI and there is no option about YUICompressor.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..when it has only to do with `i` then `Turkey test` comes to my mind.

The upper case `i` in Turkish is not `I`, it is `I` with a dot on it. When string manipulations are used with `toUpperCase()` or something then you must pay attention or your program won't run fine on turkish operating systems.

Example:

```
"fail".toUpperCase().equals("FAIL")
```

This code tries to do case-insensitive string comparison, but it fails on turkish systems.

When you're using a turkish system then try running it on another non-turkish system and tell us if the bug with YUICompressor still exists.

Comment: I understood, It could be something like that at the moment of the converstion. It would explain why only the "I" is being affected.

Comment: I dont know how I discover if my system is turkish or not.

Answer (score 0):

Is your character set UTF-8? If other, do you specify it (either as command line, or as argument to InputStreamReader/OutputStreamWriter)? 
If using as servlet, do you set encoding on both request and response?

I've integrated yui compressor with my application today (version 2.4.7) and it is processing unicode characters correctly, so you may be missing one of above steps.

Comment: It's UTF-8. I specify both, request and response. I do really think it's a bug because the problem is only with the "Í" and "í" chars. All the others special chars are correctly coverted. Please, try to compress a js file with those chars and tell me if it's really OK.

Thanks.

Comment: They've compressed OK. Just the servlet request and response encoding needed to be explicitely set.